# Returning rows between dates only working intermittently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that aims to extract the number of items on separate days from each city and then return a percentage of the cities total; all from one single df. The problem is, despite definitely being present in the df, and the total length of each city being correct; some dates return 0 for length (printed at <1>). This seems to be the same dates for each city that are returning 0 for length. Note that I printed the actual dates (<2>) it was searching between and they are correct.bizarre!

I am pretty certain the problem is in the line <3> (just bellow <2>).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def getdays(df,cities):
    df['tweet_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tweet_date']) 
    start_dates = get_dates2('28-05-2020','13-06-2020')
    end_dates = get_dates2('29-05-2020','14-06-2020')
    y_values = {}
    aa = []
    for city in cities:
        citydf = df[df['city']==city]
        citysum = len(citydf)
        print(city,citysum)
        for start_date,end_date in zip(start_dates,end_dates):
            print(start_date,end_date) <2>
            day = df.loc[(df['city']==city) & (df['tweet_date'] > start_date) & df['tweet_date'] <= end_date)] <3>
            try:
                print(len(day)) <1>
                dayperc = round((len(day)/citysum)*100,)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print([city,start_date,end_date])
                pass
            aa.append(dayperc)
        y_values[city] = aa
    return y_values

print(getdays(alltweets,cities))
```

Comment: Are you confident `get_dates2` works? - does it produce datetime vaslues?

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of the DataFrame and `start_dates` and `end_dates` - please read [mre]